# FileHelpers.ConvertException using format dd/MM/yy HH:mm

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion, filehelpers

I have a column in CSV with value: 14/04/20 09:44

> FECHA_FRANQUEO|ID_INCIDENCIA|CIF|PERSONA_CONTACTO
>   14/04/20 09:44|7093927|bbbbbbbbb|RAFA
>   14/04/20 09:02|7093933|aaaaaaaaa|Maria / Roger

I use FileHelpers in C# for read CSV file.

```
[Serializable]
[FileHelpers.DelimitedRecord("|")]
public partial class ArchivoCliente
{
    [FileHelpers.FieldHidden]
    public int Indice { get; set; } // int, not null

    [FileHelpers.FieldConverter(FileHelpers.ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm")] // "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"
    public DateTime FECHA_FRANQUEO { get; set; } // datetime2(7), not null
    public string ID_INCIDENCIA { get; set; } // nvarchar(7), not null

    public string CIF { get; set; } // nvarchar(9), not null
    public string PERSONA_CONTACTO { get; set; } // nvarchar(50), not null

}
```

I get the error:

> FileHelpers.ConvertException: Error Converting 'FECHA_FRANQUEO' to
>   type: 'DateTime'.  Using the format: 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm'

I use

```
  [FileHelpers.FieldConverter(FileHelpers.ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm")] // "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"
  public DateTime FECHA_FRANQUEO { get; set; } // datetime2(7), not null
```

or

```
[FileHelpers.FieldConverter(FileHelpers.ConverterKind.DateMultiFormat, "dd'/'MM'/'yy HH:mm", "dd/'MM/yy HH:mm")] // "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"
public DateTime FECHA_FRANQUEO { get; set; } // datetime2(7), not null
```

This code works:

```
        var ff = "14/04/20 09:44";
        var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(ff, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like the inputted value is FECHA_FRANQUEO. Can you please share a sample of your input file and your class attributes (like DelimitedRecord()]

Comment: `[FileHelpers.DelimitedRecord("|")]`

Comment: You need to skeip the first record [IgnoreFirst(1)]

Comment: Working adding `[IgnoreFirst(1)]`

Answer (score 1):

*[FileHelpers.IgnoreFirst(1)]* for ignore first line.

```
[Serializable]
[FileHelpers.DelimitedRecord("|")]
[FileHelpers.IgnoreFirst(1)]
public partial class ArchivoCliente
{
    [FileHelpers.FieldHidden]
    public int Indice { get; set; } // int, not null

    public string COMUN_COD_FORMULARIO { get; set; } // nvarchar(30), not null

    [FileHelpers.FieldConverter(FileHelpers.ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")] // "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"
    public DateTime COMUN_FECHA_FRANQUEO { get; set; } // datetime2(7), not null
```